# jQuery miniColors colorpicker not positioned right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, color-picker

I am using jQuery [miniColors colorpicker](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/02/jQuery-minicolors-a-color-selector-for-input-controls/) but in the sample code the picker appears right next to the field and button, in my case it appears at the very bottom of my document, it is as if it can't read in the position data of the button calling it.

Anyone had a similar issue with this plugin?

Here is what my code looks like (before jQuery initializes this as a color-picker)

```
<p style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;margin-left:10px;'>
    <input type='text' class='color-picker miniColors' name='data_0' id='data_0' size='6' value='".$data[0]."' />
</p>
```

. And after I run this code on it.

```
$('#data_0').miniColors({
   change: function(hex, rgb) {     $('#slide_bg').css("background-color",hex); }   
});
```

. It looks like this.

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;margin-left:10px;">
<input type="text" class="color-picker miniColors" name="data_0" id="data_0" size="6" value="#ffffff" maxlength="7" autocomplete="off">

<span class="miniColors-triggerWrap">
<a class="miniColors-trigger" style="background-color: #ffffff" href="#"></a>
</span>

</p>
```

. And the actual colorpicker gets inserted at the very last of my  (so right before the  and looks like this:

```
<div class="miniColors-selector color-picker miniColors" style="left: 116px; ">
    <div class="miniColors-hues">
        <div class="miniColors-huePicker" style="top: 0px; "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="miniColors-colors" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); ">
        <div class="miniColors-colorPicker" style="top: -5px; left: -5px; ">
            <div class="miniColors-colorPicker-inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

. And appears below the footer of my page =(

As you can see it has a value for left:116px but nothing for the vertical positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider trying [MiniColors 2.0](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/02/jquery-minicolors-a-color-selector-for-input-controls/), which changes the way positioning is handled for the dropdown. This version is a complete rewrite of the original one.  We also added a number of new features that you may find useful.

Comment: Version 2.0 and 2.1 are still not consider the position automatically. If the color select input is position at the bottom of the page the document will have a scroll when opening the color choose dialog. There is a option to select a position:top but then the color dialog will always open on the top of the input. If you like to do it automatically you need to use the Show event.

Comment: Correct, the plugin doesn't currently support viewport detection. You can use the `show` event in conjunction with [these filters](https://gist.github.com/claviska/7240757) to change the positioning dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the field inside a paragraph and define the position of paragraph with css and it will work.

E.g. -

```
<p style="position: absolute; left: 100; top: 100; margin-left: 10px;">
 <input type="input" name="color-picker" class="color-picker" size="7" />               
</p>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your interest in my issue. I have added sample code above, your solution with <p> didnt' work out of the box. Now, I don't want absolute positioning, but I tried it and it still doesn't work so the problem must be someplace else...

Comment: I resorted to using this instead, works perfectly. http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

This is how I solved it. Solution is a bit jerky though.
I used `show callback` and add remove classes based on view

```
// add jquery function removeClassPrefix
$.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
  this.each(function(i, it) {
    var classes = it.className.split(' ').map(function(item) {
      return item.indexOf(prefix) === 0 ? '' : item;
    });
    it.className = classes.join(' ');
  });

  return this;
};
// add more selector expressions to jquery
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  'off-top': function(el) {
    return $(el).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop();
  },
  'off-right': function(el) {
    return $(el).offset().left + $(el).outerWidth() - $(window).scrollLeft() > $(window).width();
  },
  'off-bottom': function(el) {
    return $(el).offset().top + $(el).outerHeight() - $(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height();
  },
  'off-left': function(el) {
    return $(el).offset().left < $(window).scrollLeft();
  }
});

// use show event 
$('#div_id').miniColors({
  theme: 'bootstrap',
  show: function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    var $minicolors = $input.parent();
    var $panel = $minicolors.find('.minicolors-panel');
    var classPrefix = 'minicolors-position-';
    $minicolors.removeClassPrefix(classPrefix);
    if ($panel.is(':off-top')) {
      $minicolors.addClass(classPrefix + 'bottom');
    }
    if ($panel.is(':off-bottom')) {
      $minicolors.addClass(classPrefix + 'top');
    }
    if ($panel.is(':off-left')) {
      $minicolors.addClass(classPrefix + 'right');
    }
    if ($panel.is(':off-right')) {
      $minicolors.addClass(classPrefix + 'left');
    }
  }
});
```